# Strings command error when using GCov on Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, mingw, gcov

Hi I am trying to use Gcov on Eclipse. After building my project and then right clicking my project -> Profiling Tools -> Profile Code Coverage. I get the following error:

*Unable to retrieve data gcov data.
The 'strings' command is required and was not found. Please install package such as minGW or Cygwin which contains the command and update your default path.*

I already have minGW installed and its path is linked to the project

Answer (score 0):

install mingw and add mingw/bin to environmental variable path. Refer the link below. 
https://mcuoneclipse.com/2017/06/18/adding-gnu-coverage-tools-to-eclipse/